# Dynamically add table row with calculation javascript

Tags: javascript

my HTML look like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Input 1</td>
        <td>Input 2</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input></td>
        <td><input></td>
        <td><input disabled></td>
        <td><button value="add">Add</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Grand Total</td>
        <td><input disabled ></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

i`m trying to calculate between two input and can add new row after that using javascrtpt... pls help me..

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with? Please show your existing code.

Comment: your question is not clear ! more info please

Comment: i dont have existing code.. the problem is im not good in javascript... i just want to calculate between two input, at the same time, i`m able to add new row, and make another calculation... thanks

Comment: as u can see from html above, i`ve got two input... for example 
input 1 = 10
input 2 = 2
total = sum of input 1 + input 2

if i press add button, i`m able to add new row and make another calculation.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in two ways give id to your table, access your table object then add a new row by table.innerhtnl+= your new rows tags. or also in this way

```
function addRow(tableID) {
        inp1 = document.getElementByID(input1).value;
        inp2 = document.getElementByID(input2).value;
        if(your Logic to check inputs)
        {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
        }
    }
```

for demo visit [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html)

Comment: wht you really want plz explain its nt clear. the above code can help you to create a row dynamically in a table. whats your other requirement????

Comment: yes...  the above code can create a row dynamically.. thank you... the problem is, at the same time, i want to make a calculation between 2 INPUT...

Comment: yeah modify the function, get the values in the above function of the two inputs, thn compare thm create some if logic then you can get the code workin exactly the way you want. !! do u want help on the logic too???

Comment: :) i hope u give me the fully working code... i appreciate your help.. thanks for understand my question... it seem like very easy to you..

Comment: check it nw you appear to be newbie to javascript. understand first the js , go through some tutorials then you will be able to do code in js